# Adding more than one path to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

Tags: ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I have the following problem when I try to add more than one path to my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in my .bashrc. Like this it won't cause any problems

> export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/alonsoj1/ros_workspace/:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

but when I try to include more than one, f.i.:

> export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/alonsoj1/ros_workspace/:/home/alonsoj1/ros/

it doesn't work and this is the kind of messages I get when I try to rosmake something:

> alonsoj1@aut-228:~/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials$ rosrun beginner_tutorials talker.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/alonsoj1/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/nodes/talker.py", line 2, in 
> import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('beginner_tutorials')
> File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/launcher.py", line 75, in load_manifest
> sys.path = prefix + _generate_python_path(package_name, [], os.environ) + sys.path
> File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/launcher.py", line 131, in _generate_python_path
> raise roslib.packages.InvalidROSPkgException("While loading package '%s': %s"%(d.package, str(e)))
> roslib.packages.InvalidROSPkgException: While loading package 'std_msgs': Cannot locate installation of package std_msgs: [rospack] couldn't find package [std_msgs]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/alonsoj1/ros/stacks:/home/alonsoj1/ros_workspace]

Also, when I try to self-complete (with TAB, I mean), I get something like this (**FIXED**, I had two trailing slashes at the end of the paths, I would have never guessed it would have mattered):

> roscd beg[rospack] warning: trailing slash found in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
> [rospack] warning: trailing slash found in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
> [rosstack] warning: trailing slash found in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
> [rosstack] warning: trailing slash found in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Any ideas?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11459/adding-more-than-one-path-to-ros_package_path?/) by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2011-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is important that you keep the original value of ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, i.e. never omit the trailing `:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` when redefining the variable:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/alonsoj1/ros_workspace:/home/alonsoj1/ros:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

Also, your paths should not end with a slash, i.e. write /home/alonsoj1/ros instead of /home/alonsoj1/ros**/**

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-10-07**:
Nice, same answer 3 minutes apart!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should try:

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/alonsoj1/ros_workspace:/home/alonsoj1/ros:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

this will do it

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-10-07**:
And simultaneous commenting!

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-10-07**:
Seems we have a talent for simultaneous answering. :-)